# Insert items into dictionary in MongoDB via C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am unable to translate working Mongo shell commands into C# code. Specifically I would like to insert a new item into a dictionary using either the  ArrayOfDocument or ArrayOfArray representation. In the example below I'd like to insert a new grade into my Pupil class.

C# Pupil class

```
[BsonId]
public string Name;
[BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]
public Dictionary<string, int> Grades;
```

Mongo shell works

```
db.myPupils.update( {"_id":"Tom"}, {$addToSet: {"Grades": {"k":"Math","v":5}}})
```

However in C# <s>I get "Specific cast is not valid"</s> *the Linq syntax does the trick*.

```
var kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Math",5);
var res = collection.UpdateOne(
        Builders<Pupil>.Filter.Eq("_id", "Tom"),
        //Builders<Pupil>.Update.AddToSet("Grades", kvp.ToBsonDocument()));
        Builders<Pupil>.Update.AddToSet(k => k.Grades, kvp));
```

I've also tried the same using `ArrayOfArrays` , Mongo shell works fine again:

```
db.myPupils.update( {"_id":"Tom"}, {$addToSet: {"Grades": ["Math",5]}})
```

C# gives "The serializer for field "Grades" must implement IBsonArraySerializer and provide item serilization info."

```
var res = collection.UpdateOne(
        Builders<Pupil>.Filter.Eq("_id", "Tom"),
        Builders<Pupil>.Update.AddToSet("Grades", new BsonArray{"Math",5});
```

What am I missing? Many Thanks for your help.

**Update**

For ArrayOfDocuments, the Linq syntax does the trick. Still no success for the ArrayOfArrays bit though...